# Find and replace a substring using regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

quick question.
I have a random string, something like this:

> **"country=='CANADA'&&(role=='MANAGERL1'||role=='ADMIN'||role=='LOC_IND')&&Age>67"**

I need to find and replace each substring that matches this pattern "role=='ROLENAME'" into

roles.indexOf('ROLENAME'), so  in this example it I want to get a new string:

> **"country=='CANADA'&&(roles.indexOf('MANAGERL1')>=0||roles.indexOf('ADMIN')>=0||roles.indexOf('LOC_IND')>=0)&&Age>67"**

How can I do this in C#, I mean using Regular Expressions (RegEx) ?
What should be the regex expression? And if you know the shortest way to do the replacement, it would help a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't said what you want to use as a replacement. [Regex.Replace Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could be a good place to start constructing your own code that we can help with.

Comment: Why would it matter what he wants to replace it with? He's asking for a regex that can match it.

Comment: I'd rather build a class that takes whatever query format this happens to be and tokenizes it internally and allows you to get back a string after you've modified any individual tokens.

Comment: Sorry, I added what I need to get ...

Comment: `roles.indexOf(...)` or `roles.indexOf(..)>=0` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the static method `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace`.

Your pattern is `@"role==('[^']*')"`.

Your replacement is `@"roles.indexOf($1)"`.

Comment: Mark, since u are an expert in Regex,  maybe u can suggest how to find and convert to lower case names of variables inside that string that matches a pattern (VarName is some name of variable):
"VarName==" or "VarName!=" or "VarName<" or "VarName<=" or "VarName>=" or "VarName>", basically the left side of the comparison, "VarName" find and convert to "varname" ?? Regex is not my strong side :)

Comment: You need the [`Replace` method with `MatchEvaluator` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.100).aspx): `Regex.Replace(input, @"(\w+)([=<>!]+)('[^']*')", match => match.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() + match.Groups[2].Value + match.Groups[3].Value);`

I've used lambda function here. It's parameter `match` contains `Groups` property. Every group matches with every pair of parenthesis in the pattern, so `Groups[1].Value` contain a name of a variable, `[2]` contains operator, and `[3]` contains a constant. The lambda method must return a single string for entire pattern.